# program loops with @Data provider even though it reaches catch statement

Tags: selenium, testng

i have 10 rows in a excel, iam looping thorugh dataprovider, when program exceutes at 2nd row exception occurs in catch,iam refreshing page, again the program automatically enters 3rd loop., can we stop the program when it reaches catch?

thanks
Mahender

Comment: Can you please share code ?

Comment: @Test(dataProvider = "Data", dataProviderClass = staticProvider.class)
 public void report(Map<String, String> dataMap) throws Exception {   try {driver.get(url)  entertext.sendkeys(datamap.get("test")...}catch{ driver.refresh}